# make Zurb Foundation dropdown the same width as their button

Tags: drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Is there a Zurb Foundation variable that we can enable so that the width of the dropdown is the same width as the button we clicked? If not, what's the best Foundation way of addressing this issue? I was hoping to add the fix to a scss file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation page for dropdown](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#) , under "Advanced" it says that you can define a maximum width for your dropdown by adding the classes "*tiny, small,medium or large*". So if your button follows this same structure then both should have the same width, or at least you could define your button's width as the same one your dropdown class has.